# PHP datastore (php-gds) - Access entity reference

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I fetched an entity of type Project. the entity has a property which is the key the the entity type User. I want to access the user property, but can't figure out how to do it.

This is my code:

```
$obj_store = new \GDS\Store('Project');
$project = $obj_store->fetchById($project_id);
echo $project->name // simple string property, works
echo $project->user->name // ?? doesn't work how do I access the user entity?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the "user" field on the "Project" entity is just a string representation of the "User" entity id, you would do it like this:

```
$obj_store = new \GDS\Store('Project');
$project = $obj_store->fetchById($project_id);
echo $project->name // simple string property, works

$obj_user_store = new \GDS\Store('User');
$user = $obj_user_store->fetchById($project->user);
echo $user->name // simple string property, works
```